# how to install .tar.bz2 file

Tags: installation

I am new to Linux and using Ubuntu, trying to install `firefox-4.0b1.tar.bz2` but don't know how to install that from the command-line. How could I do so?

Comment: just rename file from fileName.bz2 to fileName.dmg and it will work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this:

```
$ bzip2 -dc firefox-4.0b1.tar.bz2 | tar -xvf -
```

It will probably uncompress you a folder with an installer source code.

If it is an installer, proceed to run it and install firefox.

If it is source code, you will probably will be able to compile and install by doing:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Otherwise, follow a readme file or instructions you find after uncompress the BZIP2 file.

Answer (score 15):

On macOS, some installers come like xxxxx.bz2 and to install such, you can simply change the extension from .bz2 to .dmg so the installer mentioned should be changed to xxxxx.dmg then you can install it right away.

Comment: I was having trouble installing one. It was like a loop of compression and uncompression don't know how to express. THanks a lot for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a good reason to install from the .tar.bz2 file? Try using your built-in package manager (probably Synaptic) to install Firefox. This will make it easier to keep track of what you have installed, among other benefits.