# Unable to start XAMPP properly on my Mac OS

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to install XAMPP so that I can work it with PHP. But I have failed to open it, however I realised that other people downloading it, it comes as a dmg extension but mine comes as a bz2 extension. Is this the error? If so, how can I solve it? if it's not, would anyone share with me whats causing the error and how to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: The .dmg is for macOS what OS are you using

Comment: @mmmmmm I use macOS Mojave version 10.14.6

Comment: So you downloaded from the wrong place

Comment: @mmmmmm I use macOS mojave version 10.14.6

Comment: @mmmmmm where should I download from?

Comment: @mmmmmm I downloaded from `https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html`

Comment: That is the correct page

Answer (score 1):

You can go check their repo https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/
you can find .dmg in "XAMPP Mac OS X/" folder

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file extension of the downloaded file manually to dmg and it will work as it should. 
I recommend to download the VM version. 
if you encounter the following error: "Error starting “XAMPP” stack: Cannot calculate MAC Address" when you trying to start the server, you can solve it by updating the Bitnami HyperKit file. 
detailed instructions in the following link:
https://pookidevs.com/solved-error-starting-xampp-stack-cannot-calculate-mac-address/

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, simply change the extension from `.bz2` to `.dmg` so the installer mentioned should be changed to xxxxx.dmg then you can install it right away just double click on it.

credit to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68201277/7048025