# xampp file can't unzip in macos bigsur

Tags: php, macos, xampp, macos-big-sur

I tried to unzip it inside the app folder but it just duplicates itself

1. xampp-osx-8.0.2-0-vm 2.bz2.cpgz
2. xampp-osx-8.0.2-0-vm.bz2.cpgz
3. xampp-osx-8.0.2-0-vm 2 2.bz2
4. xampp-osx-8.0.2-0-vm 2 3.bz2
5. xampp-osx-8.0.2-0-vm 2.bz2
6. xampp-osx-8.0.2-0-vm.bz2
   and goes on...

How can I install XAMPP now?

Comment: How exactly did you try?

Comment: @biesior Thanks for your response. I solved this error as like this error is no more.

Comment: Just rename the file and add .dmg to the end. Something like xammp8.dmg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ohh Yeah!! That's solved now.

This is the common error in macOS higher versions especially in macOS bigsur
For this, Download the `.dmg` file instead of downloading the archive file from the apachefriendly site use:

[1]: https://xampp-for-mac-os-x.en.uptodown.com/mac/download to download the .dmg file of XAMPP.
For me, it works fine all servers are running well.

Also, don't forget to upvote if your error is resolved.

ThankYou Community

Comment: On macOS, some installers come like xxxxx.bz2 and to install such, you can simply change the extension from .bz2 to .dmg so the installer mentioned should be changed to xxxxx.dmg then you can install it right away.

credit to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68201277/7048025